# Iroun Router different css on different route

Tags: css, meteor, iron-router

Lets assume I have two routes which require two different css as follows.

`/home`

needs

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home.css">
</head>
```

And

`/dashboard`

needs

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dashboard.css">
</head>
```

I can't put both css in same head file as they are conflicting. I can't do something as below.

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dashboard.css">
</head>
```

Is there any way to put different css for different route's in head?

> Note: I need css in head to avoid glitch.

Answer (score 2):

You can use different layouts for the two routes.

```
<template name="css1">
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dashboard.css">
</head>
  <div class="main">
    {{> yield}}
  </div>
</template>
```

and

```
<template name="css2">
  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/home.css">
</head>
  <div class="main">
    {{> yield}}
  </div>
</template>
```

and use it in the layout option for the route like:

```
this.route('path to css1', {
  path: '/',
  layoutTemplate: 'css1',
  template: "css1 template"
});
```

Or alternatively:

You could do:

```
<template name="layout">
  <head>
  {> yield region="css"}}
</head>
  <div class="main">
    {{> yield}}
  </div>
</template>
```

and

```
this.route('path to css1', {
  path: '/',
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  template: "css1 template"
  yieldTemplates: {
  'temple having css1': {to: 'css'}
  }
});
```

Comment: I don't think the first way would work because meteor does not put the head tags inside template tags into the final aggregated header of html

Answer (score 0):

Meteor compiles all your CSS in a way similar to Rails' asset pipeline.

Your question is coming from a non-single page app mindset.

You can put different stylesheets for different pages, in a multiple page site. But how will this work for an app that is only one page?

Instead, you should scope your style rules.

IE, instead of `.container { color: blue }`, do something like `.container .home-container { color: blue }`.

Comment: You are right, single page mind set would be to use common CSS layout. In my app architecture, URL starts with /dashboard is SPA e.g /dashboard/stats, /dashboard/user while URL starts with /home is another SPA. Both would be having different layout.

Comment: If you have two separate apps, why do you need to share styles?

Comment: Actually I don't need to share style in this case. App starting with /home should have different style set while app starting with /dashboard should have different.